# Can Solr boost on "numField" when doing a group query

Tags: solr, lucene

Using Solr 4.0+. I have a parent-child relationship in SQL between Stores and Products.  We want to write a query that says "find all Stores where the storename, address, or city match 'xxx'.  Or where a store contains a product that matches 'xxx'.  Boost by ^y for every product found at a location. Then order by score desc"

The documents we create for indexing look like this:

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">22</field>
  <field name="locationname">Store 1</field>
  <field name="locationaddress">1 Main St</field>
  <field name="locationcity">Oakland</field>
  <field name="loc">37.842023000000,-122.251423000000</field>
  <field name="product">Product Name 1</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">22</field>
  <field name="locationname">Store 1</field>
  <field name="locationaddress">1 Main St</field>
  <field name="locationcity">Oakland</field>
  <field name="loc">37.842023000000,-122.251423000000</field>
  <field name="product">Product Name 2</field>
</doc>
```

Using the basic query as a starting point:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=xxx&fl=id, locationname, score&group=true&group.field=locationname&sort=score desc&qf=numFound^5
```

Is there any way to use numFound as part of a boost or filter query?  It seems that your query does not have access to this returned property.  Would the only options be to either restructure your data for indexing, or to pull the grouped by results into some mid-tier application and apply the scoring logic there?